# How can I create queries with sort and where in MongoDB with Spring Repository interface?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-repositories

I am trying to make a specific query in a MongoDB collection with SpringBoot. There are lots of results with the query [that can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW30q.png). I am trying to sort and filter the results as I did in MongoDB compass in the screenshot and get ONLY the latest entry in the query results.

***TaskRepo.java***

```
public interface TaskRepo extends MongoRepository<Task, String> { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoRepository help you to query document with attributes of resource (entity), when you want to query with attributes of sub-resource (embedded entity) you can use `@Query` to declare finder queries directly on repository methods

```
public interface TaskRepo extends MongoRepository<Task, String> {

    @Query("{'meta.idf' : ?0, 'method': ?1}).sort({'meta.date': -1}")
    public List<Task> findBySubResourceAndSort(String id, String method);
}
```

Or you can use MongoTemplate (refer this document https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html)